# How do i sort array of structure inputs alphabetically?

Tags: c, arrays, string, structure

so here's one function part of my overall program for a textbook exercise where there are 12 seats on a plane and each seat has its own structure consisting of a seatID, passenger first name and last name.The marker just tells the program that the seat is occupied and in this case we only look at occupied seats.  Now I've already completed the portion of having the function output customer's data (structure members containing user-entered strings) in a list. But now i would like to sort it alphabetically by last name. All I know is that I could somehow use strcmp, but syntax-wise i don't know what to put after the if(strcmp(...)) statement.

```
struct seatPlan{  
    char seatID[4];
    int marker;
    char lastName[25];
    char firstName[25];
};



void passengerList(struct seatPlan seats[], int size){

    int i=0;
    int n;
    printf("\n");
    printf("First Name\tLast Name\tSeat ID\n");
        while(i < 12){
              if(seats[i].marker == 1) { 
                  int j,item;
                       if(strcmp(seats[item].lastName,seats[j].lastName) > 0){
                           //missing code     

                       }
               }

        printf("%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\n", seats[i].firstName, seats[i].lastName, seats[i].seatID);
        i++; 
        }                 
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not writing a custom comparison function for qsort? If not, do that.

Comment: Rather than have someone do it for you why don't you think how you would sort simple ordered set of physical objects by size, and encode that. Then you could look up in a text book, bubble sort, heap sort, tree sort, quicksort etc.

Comment: If you follow @midor's suggestion you could easily extend it to sort by `lastName` and `firstName` as there is a high chance of two or more people having the same `lastName`.

Comment: Search for "qsort tutorial" in Google to get started.